# when domain is specified the cookie is not generated

Tags: php, cookies

i'm trying to configure the subdomains for a cookie for a old application in the place where start the session i've configurated like following

```
<?php
  //...
  session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.local', false, false);
  session_name('myapp');
  session_start();
```

i want share the cookie for a.local and b.local domains but when i set the domain to `'.local'` the cookie isn't genearate

if I set to  `''` the domain the cookie is generate again i dont know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot set cookies for a whole [TLD](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-Level-Domain). It would be a large security risk if it were possible to set a cookie for all .com-domains.